# How to refresh Expandable Listview's groupview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to achieve a function of when I click the group the activity will do something background and when it has finished ,I want the groupview has something different.So I want to know how to fresh the groupview.

Answer (score 1):

Well you better post some code to get the right advice on your issue but based on the text inside your question I can suggest these steps,

- `setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener(){..});` on your expandable listview.

You will get `onGroupExpand` method where you will write your logic to refresh or do whatever you need to do in background in an **Asynctask** obviously.

- Once you are done with the background work then inside `onPostExecute()` of your `Asynctask` set the adapter again or just call `notifydatasetchanged` if you have modified the data a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But I want something like a "refresh progressbar" on the group.As it is a refresh button,the group has already expand,and the notifydatasetchanged  counld only refresh the childviews.So how can I let the progressbar missing or appear as I want?I tried to declare global variables of the item of the groupview,but nothing affected

Comment: That's more of a UI Concern You better inflate the `expandable list` with the progressbar present inside and then properly execute it , just a suggestion